# How do I save the markup change I made, when going from one page to the next?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So heres the thing. I have the following:

I am making a website and each site has the same nav-bar, where you are to login. So, I made a universal navbar.php that I include in all my pages. I also made the functionality when you login, over this navbar an ajax call is sent to retreive the correct user and the markup of the navbar is changed. But when I go to other pages the navbar resets to it's initial state. How do I keep this nav-bar state when moving from page to page. Also, when I press refresh it resets.

I was thinking when I login, initially to set a global variable in my javascript file, but that doesn't seem to work since, it looks like with every page reload, it's as if the javascript is also reloaded from the beginning. How is this normally done?

Comment: You can use $_SESSION and store login values in session variable and check it on header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is analogous to client session-storage in your case.

Answer (score 0):

- You can save your data into Local-storage or session storage (angular js)
- amplify